# Prevent deletion of items that are locked

Tags: tfs

Does anyone know if there is a way to prevent items that are at state "Closed" from being deleted? Or maybe there is a workaround type of way to do this?

We work in a regulated environment so we have a condition where we cannot delete items once they are closed(as they also go into read only) unless its for maintenance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way to control this base on work item state. The workaround would be disable the "Permanently delete work items" and "Delete and restore work items" permission for normal users.